# is it possible to insert data using sql injection in select statement?

Tags: sql-injection

First of all i am testing it on my server for learning purpose.
The condition here is i want to insert a entry in test table in database and

```
SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `name` LIKE '% ".$name." %';
```

here $name is coming from a input box which is created by me. And another most important thing is nothing will be printed on frontend if query execute correctly. That's why i am trying to insert the data.

I am trying it by using union query but it is not working at all. Please let me know if it is possible or not.

Here is the query that is working in phpmyadmin but same query is not working on frontend

```
SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `name` LIKE '%mike%' OR 1=1 UNION INSERT INTO test (`id`,`value`) VALUES (36,'testdata')
```

Comment: No, that usually will not work (on commond DBMS etc.)

Comment: but it is working in phpmyadmin here is the query i am checking  SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `name` LIKE '%mike%' OR 1=1 UNION INSERT INTO test (`id`,`value`) VALUES (36,'testdata')

Comment: After implementing your query, you can test for possible sql injection vulnerabilities  by using some automated tools, such as [Sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by not working on the front end?  Is it giving an error message/exception?  If so, please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: What is the backend DB?  You normally can't union in an insert like that, but there are ways to concatenate multiple SQL statements or functions that are available with different DBs that can be used to perform DML within a SELECT.

Comment: database i am using is mysql, and i tried that query in phpmyadmin, and it is working fine but when i apply same query from input box it is not working , even i echo the query before goes into the ( echo $sql; query($db,$sql); ) this echo give me exact same query but it is not executing